# Cannot add media to a page

Tags: pages

I am unable to add media to a page. I click the button on the page edit page and nothing happens. The web console of firefox says "TypeError: wp.Uploader is undefined". I already tried deactivating installed plug-ins and I set the default theme ("Twenty Fourteen"). I googled this problem and I only find people who are developing their own plug-ins who have this problem. :(

Comment: You might try reinstalling WordPress.

Comment: May be some plugin is interfering. Try disabling plugins and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically you need to open your “wp-config.php” file in the root of your WordPress Install.
>   Search for this line:
>   require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
>   And just before it add this code:
>   define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
>   Now your WordPress Install should be fixed!

Source:
http://www.carnfieldwebdesign.co.uk/blog/wordpress-fix-add-media-button-not-working/

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError: wp.Uploader is undefined` error is coming, because wp media editor file is not included. Please check for this.